# How to inspect if a element changed there text

Tags: robotframework, playwright

We need to inspect when the text on a element change, because it is one way to see if the process ended, so we made something like this:

```
*** Settings ***
Library          Browser
*** Test Case ***
...
Then inspect if the element text is Finished
*** Keywords ***
Then inspect if the element text is Finished
sleep                                                      10
${text} =                                                  Get Text                                                      //*[@id="situacaoUltimaMovimentacaoVariacaoCambial"]
Should Be Equal                                            ${text}                                                      Finished
```

But I don't think using sleep for this is a good idea, you guys know some solution for doing this in a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @senaid I found a good solution.

Because Playwright will always wait until try to do some commands, I used Click on the element with the text that will be find after the process finished. So the code will be:

```
*** Settings ***
Library          Browser
*** Test Case ***
...
Then inspect if the element text is Finished
*** Keywords ***
Then inspect if the element text is Finished
Click                                                          //*[@id='situacaoUltimaMovimentacaoVariacaoCambial' and contains(text(),'Finished')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below mentioned method:

For Example xpath of the element initially--> **//*[@id='anyid' and contains(text(), 'Started')]** and finally --> **//*[@id='anyid' and contains(text(), 'Finished')]**

```
*** Settings ***
Library          Browser
*** Test Case ***
...
Then inspect if the element text is Finished
*** Keywords ***
Then inspect if the element text is Finished
Wait Until Page Contains Element      //*[@id='anyid' and contains(text(), 'Finished')]    60s
```

The Keyword **Wait Until Page Contains Element** will wait until the element with id - 'anyid' and with text - 'Finished' for 60 seconds. If text not changed then testcase will fail.

You can also use **Wait Until Element Contains** Keyword

```
Wait Unitl Element Contains    //*[@id='anyid']    Finished    60s
```

Comment: Hello Roby, thanks for the suggestion, but in this case we are using the Browser Library and not the SeleniumLibrary. We are using the Playwright because other tests needed and we are trying to keep it as default, unless there is no option to Playwright like "Wait Until Element Contains".

Comment: Playwright will wait for element by default:
https://playwright.dev/docs/navigations#wait-for-element

So you could use this method to wait for element with text=Finished

`await page.locator('text=Finished').waitFor();`

Comment: Thanks @senaid you reminded me about Playwright always wait, I didn't use wait for on robot framework but that makes me solve the problem using Click.